# How do you use binoculars in BF4 campaign

Tags: battlefield-4

Trying out Battlefield 4 single player. 5 mins in I see the abandoned factory. One of my squad hands me binoculars and tells me to designate targets.

What's the button to use binos?

I'm on PC

Comment: I couldn't find the button, but it came up when I scrolled through all my weapons.

Comment: Not happening for me :(

Comment: Oh. If I scroll -down- I get to it. Well that's good. Post an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Alternately you can hold down the Q button

Comment: Any way to zoom while using binocs?

Comment: Yes, there are 2 or 3 zoom levels, when you are using the bino's i think it is T to zoom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the binoculars by scrolling down or holding down <kbd>Q</kbd>. You should then be able to zoom using <kbd>T</kbd>.

Comment: There is also currently a bug where if you have "click to zoom" enabled then you won't be able to bring up the binocs properly. The temp fix is to revert to holding the button down to aim.

Comment: For those that have remapped controls, holding down *Spot/Communications* opens binocs